# WT: Paste multiple lines to Windows Terminal without executing

Tags: paste, multiline, windows-terminal

In the original PowerShell console it was possible to paste and edit multiline commands before executing it

For example this multiline script:

```
Write-Host "===== 1 ====="
Write-Host "===== 2 ====="
Write-Host "===== 3 ====="
Write-Host "===== 4 ====="
```

results in the following output

[image: powershell 7 console with multiline paste]

Unfortunately, in the Windows Terminal pasting of the same script results in a very different output

[image]

Any ideas how to "fix" the multiline pasting in the Windows Terminal?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/7482

Comment: @dashesy, your GitHub issue is about the warning. My question was about what happens after the warning and how the lines are process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution for me was to just comment out a line in the terminal **setting.json** with ***{ "command": "paste", "keys": "ctrl+v" }***

[image]

And then it works - here the expected output

[image: working output]

**Edit:**

After uncommenting the Ctrl+V chord in the settings.json, the paste functionality is ensured by the **PSReadLine** module (see *Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord ctrl+v*) but Ctrl+V will stop to work in other shells - use ***Shift+Ctr+V*** instead

Comment: great solution - sort of feels counter intuitive that commenting out the ctl+v line in settings means that ctl+v now works ... but it does work so I'm happy!
What do you mean when you refer to "the Ctrl+V chord in the settings.json"?

Comment: It means the text in the red box

Answer (score 0):

Also pasting with right click will run each line right away.  Also control-v makes it easier to paste unicode characters (at least in cmd/powershell console).  Note that control-v gets remapped with psreadline's emacs edit mode option.

Answer (score -4):

I know it is not ideal you can convert linebreaks to semicolons

```
Write-Host "===== 1 =====";Write-Host "===== 2 =====";Write-Host "===== 3 =====";Write-Host "===== 4 ====="
```

Online converter [here](https://www.gillmeister-software.com/online-tools/text/remove-line-breaks.aspx).

Answer (score -8):

Just tick the check box for highlighted setting

[image]

Comment: The question is about the "Windows Terminal" application, not about the console executable.